# ClientDataSet 'Insufficient memory for this operation'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tclientdataset

Estou tentando dar um `active` em um `ClientDataSet` e está retornando o seguinte erro:

> edbclient Insufficient memory for this operation

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada neste link pra ver se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424866/insufficient-memory-when-running-query-in-delphi-7-using-bde-paradox-7

Comment: obrigado!!!.....

Comment: Se alguma das soluções que te passei resolveu seu problema, você pode adicionar ela como resposta para que também ajude outras pessoas que enfrentarem o mesmo problema.

Comment: não resolveu :(

Comment: qual componente de relatório você está utilizando?

Comment: estou utilizando o report builder

Comment: Não consigo executa o comando `cds.LogChanges := false` antes de dar um `active` true, e o problema está dando na hora de ativar o cds :(...

Comment: Parece ser um problema da Midas.dll, veja [nesse link](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2364)

Comment: ok, vou ver, valew cara :)

Comment: não resolveu não :(

Comment: Você esta utilizando o BDE? Talvez seja necessário alterar os campos de BLOBS TO CACHE e BATCH COUNT nas propriedades do BDE.

Comment: Verifique o tamanho do processo que queira fazer dentro do ClientDataSet, se isso custará muita memória quando voce clica em active, caso aconteça realmente isso deve ser por motivo de um retorno de sql muito grande.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente isso acontece quando se tem muitos dados a serem retornados.
Como não está explícito o que você pretende fazer, sugiro tentar utilizar o `FetchAll`.

```
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['FetchAll'] := 'False';
```

Lembrando que se o se o problema for realmente no número de registros retornados do banco, caberia talvez uma reanálise da regra de negócio.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está relacionado ao BDE e a forma como ele utiliza a memória para realizar suas operações. Todo programador Delphi já passou por isso e normalmente amaldiçoou o BDE por este comportamento. Recomendo fortemente que você reconsidere o uso do BDE e passe a usar uma tecnologia mais nova, como FireDAC ou UniDAC.

Para resolver, abra o **BDE Admin**, clique na aba **Configurations**. Clique no sinal de **+** existente ao lado de **System** e em seguida clique em **INIT**. Do lado direito da tela vai aparecer uma série de configurações, uma delas se chama **SHAREDMEMSIZE** que deve ter um valor de **2048**. Altere este valor para **4096**, dê um ENTER e aplique a alteração pressionando **CTRL+A**. Reinicie a aplicação que está usando o BDE e verifique se o erro persiste.

Referências a outros erros, bem como suas soluções são encontrados no seguinte link

http://aflsistemas.com.br/blog/2009/08/17/solucao-para-os-erros-do-bde-relacionados-a-memoria/